# Insert Image on RHS of Cursor postion in vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have tried the following code copied from various websites but I am no programmer. I want the image to load at the right hand side of the screen in Word opposite the cursor position. 
Currently it loads at the top of the document or the centre of the first page if I use
.Top = wdShapeCenter

The code is as follows:

```
Sub Apic()
'
' APic Place Picture at Cursor
'

Dim openDialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim shp As Shape

Set openDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  openDialog.Filters.Clear
  openDialog.Filters.Add "JPEG Files", "*.jpg"
  openDialog.Filters.Add "Gif Files", "*.gif"
  openDialog.Filters.Add "PNG Files", "*.png"
  openDialog.Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
  If openDialog.Show Then
    imageName = openDialog.SelectedItems(1)
  End If

  Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture( _
     FileName:=imageName, _
       SaveWithDocument:=True, _
      Anchor:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range)
    With shp
    .Name = "PictureInsert"
    .LockAspectRatio = True
    .WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = False
    .WrapFormat.Side = wdWrapTight
    .WrapFormat.Type = 1
    .RelativeHorizontalPosition = _
         wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
    .RelativeVerticalPosition = _
        wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
    .Left = wdShapeRight
'    .Top = wdShapeCenter
  End With
End Sub
```

> **EDIT - from below**

modified the code as below and if now puts the image on the RHS but at the top of the first paragraph not at the cursor. Am I right in thinking the code `Anchor:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range)` is the culprit?

If so what should this be changed to?

**Here is the current code change:**

```
With shp
   .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapTight
   .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
   .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin
   .Left = wdFrameRight
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your horizontal position using the vertical constant

Try switching:

```
.RelativeHorizontalPosition = _
     wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
```

To:

```
.RelativeHorizontalPosition = _
     wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin
```

> **EDIT - Add code to insert picture after cursor:**

To add shape after cursor try inserting this just *before* your `Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture` command. It will create a new paragraph and that will move all the text after the cursor to a new paragraph, then jump to the start point of this paragraph.

```
Selection.InsertParagraphAfter
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, count:=1
```

Comment: Yes thanks I spotted that error. I have also modified the code as below and if now puts the image on the RHS but at the top of the first paragraph not at the cursor.  Am I right in thinking the code "Anchor:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range)" is the culprit?  If so what should this be changed to?  Here is the current code  change:
 
 With shp
        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapTight
        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin
        .Left = wdFrameRight
   End With

Comment: The paragraph anchor is what you specified - to get it to use the cursor position you can try adding new paragraph at cursor then add your shape. I'll update my answer